# Force File Browser to Sort files by Name

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button that opens a file browser and select multiple files, then adds them to a `ListView`.

How can I force the Browser Dialog Box to always sort the files by name before being added to the `ListView`?

Sometimes windows defaults to Date Modified or another sorting method besides Name.

---

Note: I have full file paths in a `List`, and just file names in the `ListView`.

```
private void btnInput_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Open Select File Window
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog selectFiles = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    selectFiles.Multiselect = true;

    // Process Dialog Box
    Nullable<bool> result = selectFiles.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        // Add Path+Filename to List
        foreach (String file in selectFiles.FileNames)
        {
            lstFilesPaths.Add(file);
        }

        // Add List Filename to ListView
        lsvFiles.Items.Clear();
        foreach (String name in fileList)
        {
            lsvFileNames.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(name));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: file browser]

Comment: How are you adding them to the list box? It might help to update your question with this information.

Comment: @andrensairr I've updated the question, I'm also using ListView instead of ListBox now.

Comment: Looks like there are still some details left unexplained, because your code example isn't complete: what is `lstFilesPaths`? Presuming `lsvFile` and `lsvlsvFileNames` are both ListViews, why have two? What is fileList? Sorting these out makes your question better, and therefore easier to answer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for hints. Doing so also has the added benefit of making you think about your code in a different way, often causing you to come up with a solution yourself.

Comment: @andrensairr Though my question is not about adding them to the ListView, only having the File Browser sort them by Name before doing anything else. I have a List for Full Paths and a ListView for Filenames only. I keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

The filebrowser itself won't sort its results by filename, you will need to do that before using them.

Given `lstFilesPaths` is a List of strings you're saving the selected file paths to for use elsewhere, try this to sort the list by file **name** adding:

```
foreach (var name in lstFilesPaths.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).OrderBy(s => s))
{
    lsvFileNames.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Or, if you'd like both your list of file paths and the list view of file names sorted, try this:

```
// Add Path+Filename to List
lstFilesPaths.AddRange(selectFiles.FileNames.OrderBy(f => Path.GetFileName(f)));

// Add List Filename to ListView
lsvFiles.Items.Clear();
foreach (var name in lstFilesPaths.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)))
{
    lsvFileNames.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Comment: If it can't be force sorted in the file browser, I may have to resort to this. Why I needed it sorted in the browser first is to make it easier for the user not to make a mistake for the way the program needs to add the order of the files. If it is sorted after adding, and the user had purposely selected files in a certain order (holding ctrl) then it would override their custom sorting, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've explicitly sorted the whole path based on the *filename*. However unlikely, I am assuming here that the file browser could return a number of files from different paths, such as those selected from a "Recent Files" type folder, or from a search operation.

Comment: Do you mean to say you actually want the file browser to show the files in a certain order *before* the user selects them?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying do to. But another user has just pointed out it may not be possible.

Comment: That is correct, you can't get the from this file browser. However you can write your own, if you feel up to it. More information [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95b9254b-2555-4b1f-8ea4-9db6df58e9a6/open-file-dialog-multislection-order-problem).

Answer (score 0):

try changing to:

```
lstFilePaths.AddRange(selectFiles.FileNames.OrderBy(x => x))
lsvFileNames.Items.Clear();
lstFilePaths.ForEach(x => lsvFileNames.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(x)));
```

Comment: That will sort them, but only after they've been added. I need them sorted by Name in File Browser before adding.

Comment: as per this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e4647afd-4e1b-4e04-b6cc-656259acc358/sorting-filenames-selected-in-multiselect-openfiledialog-control-in-cnet#638dc8b9-dd1f-4a36-9b1f-9f7c547f1903), there is no documented property or API to set the sort order on OpenFileDialog